# Python 3- how to use libraries to download file with URL -silent install

Tags: python, python-3.x

Solution: using Python 3 libraries to download file with a URL and silent install using ssl, urllib.parse, requests

```
#convert to string
url = str(url) 

#convert ftp download path to http and remove chars to make it downloadable 
httpurl = re.sub("ftp://","https://",url)
print("url is: " + url)


#function to break file name from the full path
def split(downloadurl):
    p,downloadexename = os.path.split(downloadurl)
    return [downloadexename]

#Remove all the unnecessary stuff you don't need
downloadurl = httpurl.replace("'","").replace(',','').replace(":2100/FTP Folders/Software","").replace(" ","%20").strip("(").strip(")")
print("Download URL is: "+downloadurl)

down_name = os.path.basename(downloadurl)
down_dir = r"C:\Desktop"
                 
#Create folder if it doesn't exist for download as required 
if not os.path.exists(down_dir):
    os.makedirs(down_dir)
full_path = os.path.join(down_dir, down_name)

# Silent Install
subprocess.call([full_path, '/Silent'], shell=True)
```

Comment: What;s the actual error you get - show the full traceback.

Comment: @barny I updated the code and now I don't see any debugging errors but also don't see the file being downloaded. Could you kindly advise, thanks!

Comment: @barny finished code

Comment: I don't see a line of code for downloading.

Comment: Yes, what happened to the requests get to do the download? I thought the download was the actual issue, your incomplete [mre] doesn’t need other details like doing the install - just show the URL and the attempt to download. Then use a mitm proxy to trace what the download from a browser does, then make your code do the same.